# split query array for every round

Tags: php, mysql

Im making a bracket that shows different games. i want to do a query and then split the array into new arrays based on what round.

im currently getting all results like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT t1.name as team1, t2.name as team2, s.round, s.score_team_1, s.score_team_2 FROM scores s
                   LEFT JOIN teams t1 on s.team_id_1  = t1.team_id
                   LEFT JOIN teams t2 on s.team_id_2  = t2.team_id
                   WHERE s.cup_id = '1'
                   ORDER BY s.round ,s.game DESC")or die(mysql_error());


if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
$rounds = array('1','2','3','4','5'); //no $ symbol
while($rs = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
print_r($rs);
}
}
```

i would like to split this array into seperated ones so all the rows that match round 1 get put into a array for round one and the ones for round 2 in the round 2 array and so on. does anyone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like that :

```
while($rs = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $rounds[$rs['s.round']] = $rs;
}
```

It will store your results in separated arrays, for example to get the results for the round 1, you will have to do :

```
$resultsForRound1 = $rounds[1];
```